# UIViewController landscape orientation changes when Camera is opened in portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

My iPad application is in Landscape. From ViewController1 I presented ViewController2. From there when camera is opened with UIImagePicker (while keeping the device in portrait mode), ViewController2 moves down a little bit and we can see ViewController1 got rotated to portrait.

[image]

Code:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;

BOOL hasCamera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
if (hasCamera){
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
    UIView *overlayView = [SCFUtility cameraOverlayViewForBounds:imagePicker.view.bounds withShapeRect:CGSizeMake(400, 560) target:self];
    imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayView;
    [overlayView addSubview:self.cameraTimerLabel];
}
else
    imagePicker.sourceType  = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

if (imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront ])
    {
        imagePicker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
    }

    [self.cameraTimerLabel setText:@"9"];
    self.cameraCountDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(cameraCountDownTimerTriggered:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
else{
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.addPhotoContainerView;
    imagePicker.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.addPhotoContainerView.bounds;
}
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
self.imagePickerController = imagePicker;
```

Comment: Can you show the codes?

Comment: @Raptor Added code

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you put a breakpoint in following callback methods (ViewController2 and ViewController1) for size change and trait collection change:

```
viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:
traitCollectionDidChange
```

And find out what is triggering rotation or view size changes.